# Refactor SQL statement with lots of common INNER JOINS and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need suggestions on how to re-factor the following SQL expression. As you can see all the selected columns except col_N are same. Plus all the inner joins except the last one in the 2 sub-queries are the same. This is just a snippet of my code so I am not including the WHERE clause I have in my query. FYI-This is part of a stored procedure which is used by a SSRS report and performance is BIG for me due to thousands of records:

```
SELECT col_A
       , col_B, col_C,...
       , '' As[col_N]
FROM table_A 
INNER JOIN table_B 
INNER JOIN table_C
INNER JOIN table_D1

UNION

SELECT col_A
       , col_B, col_C,...
       , (select E.field_2 from table_E AS E where D2.field_1 = E.field_1 AND A.field_1 = E.field_2)     AS [col_N]

FROM table_A as A
INNER JOIN table_B 
INNER JOIN table_C
INNER JOIN table_D2 as D2
```

Comment: In your second select query the sub-query in select is returning multiple columns, when you have a sub-query in select it must return a single / scalar value. Instead of having `SELECT *` you can mention a column name there and make sure it returns only one value back.

Comment: The point of this query is to get DISTINCT records for the report, the union of the first query having a join on table_D1 with the second query having a join on table_D2 is purposeful. UNION returns DISTINCT records so this is actually quite a good way to get records that have reference record in table_d1 and NOT in table_D2 and visa versa.

Add a progress spinner while the report loads. Reports take time to load. This shouldn't take more than a couple seconds with thousands of records.

Comment: If performance is a factor, add a where clause so you are not selecting the whole darn database.

Comment: Also, where are the `ON` clauses for the `INNER JOIN`s ?

Comment: Just a suggestion: Create a view joinning A,B,C

Comment: @M.Ali - I dont have a select * in my query. That was a typo

Comment: @DanBracuk - I already have a where clause. Included that in the description now

Comment: @Turophile - Ofcorse! I have ON clauses. This is just a snippet :-)

Comment: @jean - your suggestion sounds good. It should ideally make a difference. Thanks!

Comment: Also, let ABC be the A,B,C join and you want ((ABC intersection D1)U(ABC intersection D2)) == (ABC intersection(D1 U D2))

Comment: Alternatively you could define the ABC join as a CTE (particularly if you are refactoring a single statement; if the same join is used in multiple statements, a view would probably be better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jean's first suggestion of creating a view by joining A, B and C worked. I created a temp table by joining ABC and then used it to achieve significant performance improvement (query time reduces to half for couple thousand records)!